# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not a subtype

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink

[My repo with example code](https://github.com/akonyaev90/orc2CH/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/ivi/Test.java)

I try use flink-OrcTableSource.

In my code I read from hdfs orc-file and write result in local filesytem.
When I run this code from Idea - works well.
When I run code in cluster - I see that trace:

```
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:2565)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2576)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs.HadoopFsFactory.create(HadoopFsFactory.java:99)
```

I think this is due with bad cluster configuration, but I haven't idea how fix it.

My environment:

read from hadoop 2.6.0 (by cloudera)

flink cluster 1.4.0 (local) on my laptop. 

java 8 (1.8.0_151)

I try run my code on flink-cluster where and received the same error.
Flink-cluster is located in the same place where the hdfs-cluster.

Comment: For me this seems to be a Hadoop error. Maybe you can tell us a little bit about your environment?

Comment: added env in post

Comment: Are you using the Flink binaries with bundled Hadoop or Hadoop-free?

Comment: I use flink binaries with Hadoop 2.6